# Rails Active Model Association Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having an issue with model associations. I want to pull a route's trip info by accessing the data from **trips.route_id** where **routes.route_id** would be the same value. Currently the SQL query is calling **routes.id**, instead using **routes.route_id**. Any help would be appreciated.

### Route Table Structure

```
COLUMNS: id,route_id,route_short_name,route_long_name,route_desc,route_type  
ROW: 1,2-36,2,"East 34th St",,3
```

The primary_key on this table is 'id'.

### Models

```rb
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trips, :foreign_key => 'route_id'
end
```

```rb
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :route
end
```

### Route Controller

```
class RouteController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @route = Route.where("'%s' = routes.route_short_name",params[:id]).first
  end
end
```

Want to call `@route.trips` to pull `trip` information associated with said `@route`

### LOG INFO

```
Started GET "/route/19" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Nov 23 21:09:55 -0500 2011
Processing by RouteController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"19"}
Route Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `routes`.* FROM `routes` WHERE ('19' = routes.route_short_name) LIMIT 1
Trip Load (8.4ms)  SELECT `trips`.* FROM `trips` WHERE `trips`.`route_id` = 15
```

**Trip Load Explanation:** `15` represents the `id` of the object returned from the "Route Load" query. I would like to use the `routes.route_id` value of the result instead of the `id` to build the "Trip Load" query.

**Desired result:**
 `Trip Load (8.4ms)  SELECT 'trips'.* FROM 'trips' WHERE 'trips'.'route_id' = '2-36'`
(`'2-36'` value is referenced from Route Table Structure example)

Comment: Is the name of primary key in `routes` `route_id`? If that, you should call `set_primary_key "route_id"` inside `Route`

Comment: Could you show us the table structure?

Comment: I guess, `route_id` is not indexed field + records set is too large. Could you post results of `show create table trips` and `explain SELECT \`trips\`.* FROM \`trips\` WHERE \`trips\`.\`route_id\` = 15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you need to change your models to something like this:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trips, :primary_key => "route_id"
end

class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :route, :primary_key => "route_id"
end
```